# How to install Debian in under 500M?

Tags: bash, debian, systemd, apt, headless

Is it possible to build a Debian system with `apt`, `bash`, and `systemd` under 500M? I tried using Debian's net-installer and opted for the most barebone settings (literally installed nothing). Then booted and removed a handful of non-essential packages. I got the system down to about 160 packages. Still, the OS is over 1G:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev
tmpfs          414M  5.6M  409M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       13G  1.1G   11G  10% /
tmpfs          2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          5.3G     0  5.3G   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          2.1G     0  2.1G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

And why is /dev so large?

I tried a bunch of [tiny OSs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79555/what-is-the-smallest-installed-size-ubuntu-based-distribution) but they have weird/confusing package manages, and/or weird/confusing methods to enable persistent filesystems, or have broken/confusing installers. I just need a super tiny Debian OS.

Comment: Few years ago I managed to install Debian 7 in 500 MB thanks to Btrfs with compression.

Comment: `/dev`'s type is `udev`.  It's not physical disk-space, it's RAM.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks. Can you elaborate? Is btrfs an available option in the net-installer? Is there a guide or walkthrough you can link to that demos how to set it up with Debian?

Comment: Delete unused kernel modules; default all modules are reserve 250MB. Delete `/usr/share/doc` folder, use `localepurge` package for removing unused languages, store apt lists in bz2 rather than plain txt...

Comment: It can be done... Debian 10, 343 packages, 699MB, already some fluff. Can cut more, but prefer it that way. debmaster10:/# dpkg -l | wc -l
343
debmaster10:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            466M     0  466M   0% /dev
tmpfs           812K  312K  500K  39% /run
/dev/sda1       4.6G  699M  3.7G  16% /
debmaster10:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release: 10
Codename: buster
debmaster10:/#

Answer (score 4):

debootstrap can be passed a variant; Right now (2020-08-19) The minbase variant for Arm64 Debian 10 is 184MB without the kernel which is about 18MB, and without systemd, and after `apt-get clean`.

There are a few projects that aim for small GNU/Linux

- OSMC is 300MB,
- Alpine Linux is 130 MB
- Termux is 69 MB
- Damn Small Linux is 50MB
- dd-wrt Mega is 26MB

and there are guides on making ones own (like Linux From Scratch).

Debian packages can be exclude and the kernel can be configured for further reduction. The issue is as soon as one wants to do something one finds oneself installing large packages.

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -rn | head
15200   coreutils
9805    perl-base
9746    libc6
6673    dpkg
6482    bash
4106    util-linux
3944    apt
3098    libapt-pkg5.0
3064    libc-bin
3036    tzdata
```

The above makes it clear why small distributions use BusyBox, custom package mangers, and avoid runtimes (perl/python/php/etc)

But with 16 TB drives and TB NVMes distribution size is not important to those outside of containers or embedded work.

Comment: `mmdebstrap` gives me a 117MiB `minbase` on Debian 10, is that “217M” a typo or did you really end up with 217MiB used?

Comment: @StephenKitt I was able to get 184MB with Debian 10 after "apt-get clean" just now (217MB was Debian 11) I'm using the arm64 architecture.

Comment: That’s intriguing, the only difference should be the `apt` clean-up (package cache and lists), which doesn’t explain the size difference... I guess I’ll compare both directly ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt note that the debstrap source has a lot of conditionals

Answer (score 1):

Not a fully functioning system.

```
# debootstrap buster /var/tmp/bustertest
# chroot /var/tmp/bustertest apt update
# chroot /var/tmp/bustertest apt install linux-image-amd64
# chroot /var/tmp/bustertest apt policy systemd
systemd:
  Installed: 241-7~deb10u4
  Candidate: 241-7~deb10u4
  Version table:
 *** 241-7~deb10u4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
# du -hsx /var/tmp/bustertest
651M    /var/tmp/bustertest
```

The only thing missing from that installation is `grub` to be able to boot it, and that is tiny. But this is still more than your 500M target.

Without the kernel it came to 365M.

> And why is /dev so large?

Because it is not on disk, it is in memory - so it reflects your RAM size, same as `/sys/fs/cgroup` does.

Comment: thanks so much. I didn't know much about chroot before this. If I added grub and bash, would it be possible to create an ISO of /var/tmp/bustertest with dd and boot it on different workstations?

Comment: You can avoid installing grub and just use systemd's built in bootloader (systemd-boot) on UEFI systems.